# Left shifting or Right shifting a integer with negative number, is it a defined behaviors?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I tried the below code and in both the cases i.e. (left shift and right shift) i got the output as 0

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=20;

    a=a<<-1;
    cout<<a;
    int x=20;
    x=x>>-1;
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I tried the below code...*  **Why** did you try it?  What did you expect?  Did you enable your compiler warning, so the compiler could tell you the code is bad?

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) | [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Although it's true that a lot of runtime errors or strange behaviours result from undefined behaviour, writing code to detect/identify undefined behaviour is unreliable.  Compilers (even if configured for maximum warnings/diagnostics) cannot reliably detect or give warnings about undefined behaviour - there are always false positives and false negatives.   Running a program with undefined behaviour (or inputs that result in undefined behaviour) is unreliable, since one *common* consequence of undefined behaviour is output that seems perfectly logical (or even well-defined) to a mere mortal.

Answer (score 6):

Shifting by a negative value triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.  This is specified in section 8.8p1 of the [C++ standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) regarding the bitwise shift operators:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater
> than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand